# How to use a switch case in test cases without passing values to switch() method

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have a enum declared in a sepearate class :

```
public enum TypeEnum {
  BUSY, RELAX;
}
```

I need to use it in Junit Test case class:

```
 public void adValues(List<String> customAttributes) {
        switch (customAttributes.get(0).toString()) { //This return either BUSY or RELAX
          case "BUSY": //I need to use Enum's here now
          case "RELAX":
           .....
           .....
```

I tried something like this:

```
TypeEnum[] ttEnum = TypeEnum.values();
    for (TypeEnum val : ttEnum) {
    switch (customAttributes.get(0).toString()) {
      case ttEnum.BUSY: //BUSY cannot be resolved or is not a field
      case RELAX: //Compile time error:RELAX cannot be resolved to a variable
      ....
```

But it is giving me compile time error, I tried some other ways too, not no success.

Is there anyway to use switch case here or I should use if-else statement here.?

Comment: "it is giving me compile time error", you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: You enum looks like it has int values.

Comment: Why do you want a switch in a test case?  A test case should follow one clearly defined path, and should not contain any branching or looping logic.

Comment: Anyway, the usual way of putting an enum into a switch is just to use the enum name without a prefix.  For example, `case BUSY:` and `case RELAX:`.

Comment: I updated the error I am getting, also I am using switch case here for code resuability and coverage.

Comment: read about how swich-case and enum works with examples.. you need mapping to String to Enum, something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56665099/3870382